# C++ Virtual Destructor Crash

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Base  
{  
public:  
    virtual ~Base();  
};  
class Derived : public Base  
{  
public:  
    virtual ~Derived();  
};  
class MoreDerived : public Derived  
{  
public:  
    virtual ~MoreDerived();  
};
```

along with an objects

```
Base* base = new Base();
MoreDerived* obj = new MoreDerived(*base);
```

There is a part of code where I need to delete the MoreDerived object using a thread, thus having to cast it to void* first. In the thread, I have

```
void KillObject(void* ptr)  
{  
    delete static_cast<Base*>(ptr);  
}
```

Non of the pointers are NULL, and `void* ptr` *IS* a MoreDerived* (or at least a Base*), but the application still crashes...

Comment: Your code sample seems incomplete -- "static_cast(ptr)" isn't legal, it needs a type specified (something like static_cast<T>(ptr)) and you should probably use reinterpret_cast anyhow. You also appear to be using a constructor for MoreDerived that you don't declare/define anywhere. Could you edit your post so that the code better reflects your real code?

Comment: Why do you think you have to cast it to `void*`?

Comment: @John: Probably because most (all?) threading libraries call a thread routine which takes a `void *`. See [ThreadProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686736.aspx) or [pthread_create](http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_create.html).

Comment: In what way does the application crash?  Can you put logging statements in the destructors to see exactly what's called here?  And how does the `MoreDerived` constructor you're using work exactly?

Comment: Why do you have to delete the object via a thread? If this is to ensure nobody is using it at time of deletion then ref-counting would be easier and more robust.

Comment: @Billy:  Ah yes, that's probably it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're thinking of `dynamic_cast<void*>` which obtains a pointer to a most-derived object.

You don't need to go through a `void*` just to delete an object of polymorphic type. Just take whatever pointer you have and `delete` it, be it a `Base*` to a `MoreDerived` object or a `MoreDerived*`. There is no need for a `Kill` method.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, a cast often results in a change of the address of the pointer. You need to cast to a `Base *` before casting to `void *`, or you have undefined behavior. (Casting to/from Void * is okay, but when casted back it needs to be the exact same type on either end)

Comment: I suppose by doing <code>Base* ptrToBase = obj;</code>, I have already done a static_cast to <code>Base*</code>??

Comment: I have updated to post as an answer. I suppose by doing <code>Base* ptrToBase = obj;</code>, I have already done a static_cast to <code>Base*</code>??

Answer (score 2):

If KillObject always deletes a `Base *`, why does it take a `void *`? Change `ptr` to be `Base *` and get rid of the cast. Then if the thing passed in is a `Base *`, a `Derived *`, or a `MoreDerived *`, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

By casting the pointer to `void *` you're removing the compiler's knowledge of how to convert up and down the inheritance tree. This is especially a problem when there is multiple inheritance, as two pointers to the same object won't necessarily have the same value!

Don't do that.

Comment: a pointer is a pointer. The compilers knowledge is in the vtable of the thing it points to; when he casts it back all should be good

Comment: @pm100, it's more complicated than that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Multiple_inheritance_and_thunks

Answer (score 2):

If you static_cast to void* then standard only guarantees that static_cast to the original pointer type will work correctly. As mentioned previously you either need dynamic_cast or need to static_cast to Base* first and then to void*. static_cast from void* to Base* should then work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much for all the responses.

Just to clarify the situation and elaborate on the code some more, I am using gcc 4.1.2 on CentOS, and he missing type in static_cast is a StackOverflow formatting error, and I have

`void KillObject(void* ptr)

{

    delete static_cast< Base* >(ptr);

};

// There is a reason for the following as this is a snipet and stuff gets passed around

Base* base = new Base();

MoreDerived* obj = new MoreDerived( * base );

Base* ptrToBase = obj;

// Use ptrToBase in code with no problems

// Delete object, illustrative only - have to cast to void* to pass to API

pthread_run( ... , KillObject , (void*)ptrToBase);`

Re Billy O'Neal: I suppose by doing `Base* ptrToBase = obj;`, I have already done a static_cast to `Base*`??

Re Mark Ransom: By printing out the pointer and steps the delete does through, I see that the pointer has the same address all the way through and it crashes at `~MoreDerived()`.

Re Potatoswatter: I think in "More Effective C++" they mentioned using `dynamic_cast< void* >` but I have failed to find that sentence again. I will give this a go and let you know the result.

Thanks again